# Task does not wait up-to the wait time

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task

I have created a task and provided the wait time to the task.wait() method, but the task does not wait up to the provided time and return before the wait time with completed status false.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
        {
            int localValue = i;
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessTask(localValue));
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void ProcessTask(int thread)
    {
        var task = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => GetSomeValue());
        task.Wait(2000);

        if(task.IsCompleted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Completed Thread: " + thread);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not Completed Thread " + thread);
        }
    }

    private static int GetSomeValue()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(400);
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Update:

I have updated the code. When I have run this code I got the following output.

[image]

Only two tasks are completed out of 10. so I want to know what is the issue with this code?

> Note: I am running this code in 4.5.2 frameworks.

Comment: It doesn't look like that code would even compile, given that you're trying to assign an `int` value to a `Tuple<int>` variable. Please provide a [mcve]. (I'd also suggest using `Task.Run` rather than `TaskFactory.StartNew`...)

Comment: @JonSkeet- By mistake Tuple was added. I updated the code. And I am using 4.0 framework so Run the method is not available.

Comment: It would be worth including that information, given how rare it is to need 4.0 these days... And you still haven't posted a [mcve] which would make it much easier to help you.

Comment: @JonSkeet- What exactly do you want in the Code? I think it is simple to understand and also explains the problem.

Comment: I want code I can copy, paste into an empty file, compile, and run - showing the problem you describe.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I am not able to give entire code over here because the code is large. Therefore, just I have given blueprint of the code.

Comment: It doesn't have to be your actual code (and shouldn't be, as that's likely to contain irrelevant parts) - it just needs to be a short but complete example that demonstrates the problem. You may well find that by constructing such an example, you find the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet- I have added the sample code. You can run this code in your machine.

Comment: It would have been better if it had been genuinely complete - ready for me to copy/paste/compile/run rather than needing to add imports and a class declaration myself. Additionally, you're not actually showing that `Wait` doesn't wait for 2 seconds - if you add logging for each thread before and after you'll see that it *does* wait for two seconds. What you're actually observing is tasks starting slowly. I'll add an answer...

Comment: (I've edited your question to show a genuine [mcve].)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't that `Task.Wait` isn't waiting long enough here - it's that you're assuming that as soon as you call `Task.Factory.StartNew()` (which you should almost never do, btw - [use `Task.Run` instead](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html)), the task is started. That's not the case. Task scheduling is a complicated topic, and I don't claim to be an expert, but when you start a lot of tasks at the same time, the thread pool will wait a little while before creating a new thread, to see if it can reuse it.

You can see this if you add more logging to your code. I added logging before and after the `Wait` call, and before and after the `Sleep` call, identifying which original value of `i` was involved. (I followed your convention of calling that the thread, although that's not quite the case.) The log uses `DateTime.UtcNow` with a pattern of `MM:ss.FFF` to show a timestamp down to a millisecond.

Here's the output of the log for a single task that completed:

```
12:01.657: Before Wait in thread 7
12:03.219: Task for thread 7 started
12:03.623: Task for thread 7 completing
12:03.625: After Wait in thread 7
```

Here the `Wait` call returns after less than 2 seconds, but that's fine because the task has completed.

And here's the output of the log for a single task that *didn't* complete:

```
12:01.644: Before Wait in thread 6
12:03.412: Task for thread 6 started
12:03.649: After Wait in thread 6
12:03.836: Task for thread 6 completing
```

Here `Wait` really *has* waited for 2 seconds, but the task still hasn't completed, because it only properly started *just* before the `Wait` time was up.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to wait for task completion, you can use property Result. The Result property blocks the calling thread until the task finishes.

`var task = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => GetsomeValue()); 
int res = task.Result;`

Comment: I am using Result property in if part. If the task is completed then I use the result of task otherwise I execute other statements.

Comment: It looks like the OP is deliberately waiting for at most 2 seconds. That's an entirely reasonable thing to do, and suggests that blocking unconditionally does not meet their use case.